# how does one systematically calculate quadratic non-residues of a $p$ ($p$ is prime)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I know how to find the quadratic residues and I know how to determine the quadratic nonresidues by simply taking the complement of the positive integers lower than *p* against the known residues; is that the only way to find nonresidues? It feels like there should be a method that's more direct.

Comment: Well, if you can find one non-residue then you can get all of them by multiplying by the squares, and reciprocity lets you find a non-square pretty easily.  Or, if you have a primitive root it's easy.

Comment: 'By taking the complement', do you mean $p-a$ is the complement of $a$. If that is what you meant, then it works only in case of odd primes $p\equiv 3 \pmod 4$. There is a standard way to decide residues and non residues. Take a non zero positive number $a$ strictly less than $p$. Then $a^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$ can have only two values $\pm 1$ modulo $p$. If the value is 1, then $a$ is a residue, if it is $-1$ then the $a$ is non residue.

Comment: Presumably the OP means the set complement.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a deterministic procedure, you can just test each residue $\bmod p$ sequentially (using Euler's criterion or quadratic reciprocity). The effectiveness of this procedure is bounded by the size $n(p)$ of the smallest quadratic non-residue $\bmod p$, which is [OEIS A053760](https://oeis.org/A053760).

It's an open problem to characterize the asymptotic growth of $n(p)$; according to [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/419177/the-actual-size-of-the-first-quadratic-non-residue), the generalized Riemann hypothesis implies $n(p) \le (\log p)^2$, and heuristically we expect $n(p) = O((\log p)^{1 + \varepsilon})$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$.

For a random algorithm you can randomly generate residues $\bmod p$ and test them. I don't know if this is expected to do better or worse than the above. **Edit:** I guess since half of all residues are quadratic non-residues this should take an average of $2$ attempts?